# Does this answer deserve bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty

This question was asked [How to make keyboard backlight Fn buttons work in Samsung Series 9?](https://askubuntu.com/q/233312/102029) for which users having trouble getting samsung-laptop module loaded in order for F* hotkeys to work as expected.

A bounty was put on this question by Alix Axel about eight days ago; for which the seven day period as well as the grace period has now ended.  There is no indication of bounty being awarded to any of the answers. Looking in helpcentre regarding bounties it says;

> How is a bounty awarded?

The bounty period lasts 7 days. Bounties must have a minimum duration of at least 1 day. After the bounty ends, there is a grace period of 24 hours to manually award the bounty. Simply click the bounty award icon next to each answer to permanently award your bounty to the answerer. (You cannot award a bounty to your own answer.)

If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts an answer during the bounty period, and the bounty expires without an explicit award – we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration.

As a special bonus, any reputation you earn from being awarded a bounty is exempt from the daily reputation cap.

Does this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/269889/102029 meet the criteria for being awarded half the bounty?

Comment: The bounty from karlingen **has** been awarded on Jul, 29 to the author of http://askubuntu.com/a/325616/117103. So you question seems obsolete, doesn't it?

Comment: @geezanansa: What made you rollback the edit done by me? Didn't it make the post more readable? I had quoted the relavent parts, removed unnecessary information and made other general improvements. Would like to hear your views on same - I'm a bit perplexed because you just rolled back without keeping any of the improvements.

Comment: Sorry Aditya as i really do not mean to cause reason for you to be concerned or upset for not accepting the edit. http://meta.askubuntu.com/revisions/7116/5  i have no option to select this edit as it has no obvious way of selecting it.  Have provided link so it easy for you to resuggest.  If you think you can see some of my concerns regarding the mentioned q & a then the real motive for posting here has not been helpful but due to the mentioned users answer being upvoted this post may have attracted the attention of the wrong kind of people.  Am in no way implying anything personal.

Comment: A blind person could see what is happening there is far from ideal.  I do no longer wish to contribute to it any more.  I have flagged and downvoted as well as posting here and asked user to chatroom so have done all that i can to help improve that q and a.  Thank you for your answer as you have at least read the q&a unlike guntbert

Comment: @Aditya - forgot to tag your name for notification  N.B. change "helpful" to "wasted"-  did not notice quick enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Alix Axel](https://askubuntu.com/users/9018/alix-axel) started the bounty on that question on 31st July 2013 and did not explicitly award the bounty to any of the answers until the end of the Grace Period.

He isn't the author of the question either. So, implicit award of half the bounty amount is the only way the bounty could be awarded in this case. [Help Center mentions the following in this regard](https://askubuntu.com/help/bounty) (emphasis mine):

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted **answer created after the bounty started** with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

So, implicit award of half the bounty amount is awarded only to those answers which are created **after** the start of that particular bounty fulfilling other requirements. Since in this case, no further answers were created after the start of bounty i.e. 31st July 2013, the bounty is lost and doesn't get awarded to anyone.

Comment: The bounty is lost and isn't awarded to anyone in this case. The user who started the bounty already lost the reputation points while initiating the bounty and he doesn't receive that back either. In short, the reputation points put up on bounty got destroyed.